# Prevent memory overwrite when using pointers in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C, and I'm getting started on programming a simple program that runs after boot, *without an OS*, so I don't have `malloc` and such.

I'm trying to understand memory management; look at this example:

```
char *a = read_string(); // gets user input string, the length is unknown.
char *b = read_string();
```

How would I know that `b` doesn't overwrite `a`?

Especially when writing a function that knows the string length only at runtime?

Comment: Those are allocated at compile-time, and are read-only.

Comment: What if you have a function that cunstructs a string in runtime?

Comment: Then you need to write your own `malloc`.

Comment: You mean i would need to account for every piece of memory ?

Comment: a and b are pointer variables; there values are the addresses of some other things (strings in your case). They *could* point to the same strings or to (parially) overlapping strings. If you don't want that, the function `read_string()` must take care not to return the same address twice. (or pointers to overlapping strings)

Comment: If you're not going to account for the memory that's used, then the o/s has to do it for you.  You said you don't have an o/s to do it for you; therefore, the workload falls on you.  An operating system is useful because it provides services such as support for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: If you don't have memory allocation in your OS yet (and a program that runs right at boot *is* the OS for all practical purposes), you cannot *store* the user input anywhere -- so you cannot *implement* read_string() yet. ;-)

Comment: Generally speaking, *learning* C in "freestanding" mode (i.e. without an OS, directly "on the hardware") is not a good idea. Learn the language *first* in an environment where you can edit-compile-run instead of edit-compile-reboot-run-reboot, where you get the benefit of debuggers and similar niceties, *then* set out to code on the bare metal. This comes from a former [OSDev](http://osdev.org) regular who has seen *hundreds* of people try what you're doing, and failing at it.

Comment: what platform and toolkit are you running on?

Comment: Nothing ... Haha , bare metal , straight off of the boot.

Comment: Thanks  everyone, I realised that i need to write my own memory manager. I just thought that maybe C has this built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll have to write my own memory manager to track allocated memory.

Thx everyone.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, everything depends on the `read_string()` function implementation. If that function correctly allocates memory for each new string, your `a` and `b` pointers will point to different strings.